# Minimize an integral of a function and its derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the function $x(t)$ that minimizes the quantity

$$\int_0^1 (x^2 +\dot{x}^2)dt$$

given that $x(0)=1$ and $x(1)$ is free (so I'm expecting the result to be a function of $x(1)$ itself).

I am however utterly lost on this. One could say that the smallest value the integral could take is $0$, and therefore solve $x^2 +\dot{x}^2 = 0 \Rightarrow \dot{x}^2 = -x^2$, but this is an ODE that I find particularly weird (and even if it does make sense, I have no idea how to solve it).

Any insight or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the [Euler Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).

Comment: Just curious, why is $e^{it}$ not a good solution to the ODE?  I've always wondered why people don't like complex solutions... `;)`

Comment: I actually thought of it as well, since that solution arises from setting $\dot{x}^2 = - x^2$ as I write above (and that just gives the value $0$ to the integral which is the minimum it can take -- technically), however for some reason it's not the proper way to go. I'll ask around and see why that is :)

And I'm guessing people don't like complex solutions because, well... they're "complex"? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $J(x) = \int_0^1 x^2 + \dot{x}^2$.

1. you can't solve the ODE because LHS is $\ge 0$ as RHS is $\le 0$, and $x(0) = 1$.
2. the method here is to consider $$x(t) = x^*(t) + \epsilon f(t)$$
   where $x^*(t)$ is the solution to your problem.
   If $x(t)$ is another input, $x(0) = x^*(0)$ so $f(0) = 0$.

Now consider the asymptotic $\epsilon\to 0$:

$$x^2(t) = [x^*(t)]^2 + 2\epsilon f(t) x^*(t) + O(\epsilon^2)$$
$$[\dot x^*(t)]^2 + 2\epsilon \dot f(t) \dot x^*(t) + O(\epsilon^2)$$

$$J(x) = J(x^*) + 2\epsilon\int_0^1 [f x^* + \dot f \dot x^*]+O(\epsilon^2)$$

Now as $J$ is minimum for $x^*$:
$$
0=
\int_0^1 [f x^* + \dot f \dot x^*] =
\int_0^1 f x^* + [f\dot x^*]_0^1 - \int_0^1 f \ddot x^*
$$

you eventually get, taking every function $f$ such as $f(0) = f(1) = 0$:
$$
x^* - \ddot x^*  = 0
$$
You can express the solution as a function of $x^*(1)$, because $x^*(0) = 1$.

Of course you need to check that this is the solution, but here just take the steps backward and there should not be any problem.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated way to go for something which I suspect has a rather simpler solution (they are exercises on basic level).

Comment: A simplier solution is very welcome.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I was editing the comment :)

@Omnomnomnom Thank you. I looked at the Euler-Lagrange equation earlier, but didn't realize that it held the secret to this problem as well. If we consider $F(t,x,\dot{x})=x^2 + \dot{x}^2$, then 

$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} -\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}} = 0 \Rightarrow x(t)=x''(t)$$,

and this I think seems correct.

Comment: My message is the way the Euler Lagrange equation is derivated...

Comment: My bad for not seeing that. The truth is, I've been up all night studying so I didn't see that is indeed the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange (silly me). However, I do thank you for your time to bother, it is much appreciated :)

Comment: You are welcome :)